# Hyperledger Cello Ansible Azure using Service Principal

Tags: azure, ansible, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I am trying to configure **Fabric network** using Cello **on Azure**. I am **using Service Principal** as the authentication method.

I have a *resource group* in Azure which I have configured in my azure.yml file with proper *subscriptionId*. But, I am getting an **Error:  Azure Error: SubscriptionNotFound\nMessage: The subscription '********' could not be found.**

Has anyone faced this error? How this can be resolved?

logs:

```
PLAY [Get start timestamp] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cloud]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cloud]

PLAY [Prepare to run the workload] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cloud]

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/cello/cello/src/operator-dashboard/agent/ansible/roles/cloud_azure/prepare/tasks/apply.yml for cloud

TASK [Setup env specific variables] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cloud]

TASK [Retrieve azure specific image details] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cloud]

TASK [Print azure image results] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cloud] => {
    "found_images": {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "azure_vmimages": []
    },
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false
    }
}

TASK [Create azure resource group] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [cloud]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating or updating resource group myresourceGroup - Azure Error: SubscriptionNotFound\nMessage: The subscription '********' could not be found."}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/cello/cello/src/operator-dashboard/agent/ansible/provcluster.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
cloud                      : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that there was an issue with Ansible scripts. Please follow this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks/issues/17) for more details.

1. **Use Ansible 2.7** if you are using AzureUSGovernment Cloud.
2. Need to configure cloud_environment as `cloud_environment: "AzureUSGovernment"` as environment variable

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscription ID is not found.

Refer to [this document from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-install-configure?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fansible%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#span-idfile-credentials-create-ansible-credentials-file) to know how to configure your service principal.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but the issue wasn't this. SubscriptionId is already configured.